# $m=17 \cdot 23 = 391$. With an exponent $e=3$ and encrypted word is $c=21$. Decrpyting exponent $d=235$. Find $w$.

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, discrete-mathematics, chinese-remainder-theorem

Say $m=17  \cdot 23 = 391$. With an exponent $e=3$ and encrypted word is $c=21$. Decrpyting exponent $d=235$. Find $w$, when $w \equiv c^{d} \pmod{m}$.

So far I have split it up like this:
\begin{align*}
w & \equiv  21^{235} \pmod{17}\\
w & \equiv  21^{235} \pmod{23}
\end{align*}

simplified to
\begin{align*}
21^{235} & \equiv 4^{235} \pmod{17}\\
21^{235} & \equiv -2^{235} \pmod{23}
\end{align*}
I don't know how to further simplify and go from there. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You want 
\begin{align*}
w& \equiv 21^{235} \equiv 4^{235} \pmod{17}\\
w& \equiv 21^{235} \equiv (-2)^{235} \equiv - (2^{235}) \pmod{23}\\
\end{align*}

Observe that $4^{2} \equiv -1 \pmod{17}$, hence $4^4 \equiv 1 \pmod{17}$. Using the division algorithm you can write $235=4(58)+3$. Thus
$$4^{235} \equiv 4^{4(58)} \cdot 4^3 \equiv 1 \cdot 4^{3} \equiv -4 \equiv 13 \pmod{17}.$$

For the second congruence you may use the following
$$2^{11} \equiv 1 \pmod{23}.$$
Thus
$$2^{235} \equiv 2^{11(21)} \cdot 2^4 \equiv 1 \cdot 2^{4} \equiv -7 \pmod{23}.$$
Thus your system of congruences become
\begin{align*}
w& \equiv 13 \pmod{17}\\
w& \equiv  7 \pmod{23}
\end{align*}

Now use Chinese remainder theorem to solve for $w$ (Hint: $w=30$).